# Can I delete leftover field_deleted_* tables?

Tags: 8, entities, database

I have a lot of `field_deleted_*` tables in the database and neither `drush cr` or running cron is removing them. Is it okay to just remove them from the database? How can I tell Drupal to remove them otherwise?

[image]

Edit: Per 4k4 troubleshooting tip:

```
➜  default git:(HUHLR-172) ✗ drush ev "var_dump(\Drupal::state()->get('field.storage.deleted'))"
array(0) {
}
```

This means:

> If this is empty, then you can remove the tables in the database as
>   well, because Drupal has no chance to guess the hash keys of the table
>   names without this information.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, this is not a good idea, because there are more things that need to be removed, not only the database tables. Deleting these tables without checking their usage first (see troubleshooting below) results in this error [Cron error message. table or view not found: 1146](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/290760/cron-error-message-table-or-view-not-found-1146)

The deleted fields are purged by cron, but only 50 rows per run. If you want to accelerate the process, run cron more often or increase the batch size in *field.settings.yml*:

```
purge_batch_size: 50
```

Instead of cron you can run `field_purge_batch()` from the command line, then with a higher batch limit, for example 1000 or how many rows you have and are able to delete without hitting a memory/time limit:

```
drush ev "field_purge_batch(1000)"
```

---

**Troubleshooting**

If cron or the drush command has no effect, even not deleting some of the rows (if there are any more rows left in the tables), then check whether there are still field storages registered for these tables:

```
drush ev "var_dump(\Drupal::state()->get('field.storage.deleted'))"
```

If this is empty, then you can remove the tables in the database as well, because Drupal has no chance to guess the hash keys of the table names without this information.

If this is not empty, then you can use this output of the field storage definition(s) to debug this further (see comment of @MarioSteinitz).

Comment: @Kevin stated, that running Cron doesn't solve his problem. So there's probably a mismatched field definition error or a not cleanly uninstalled module preventing the purge batch from running without errors?

Comment: Yeah, cron is having no effect.

Comment: Looks like the troubleshooting tip provided 0 results, so I went ahead and deleted them from the DB.

Comment: @Kevin ran into this issue too and cron does not seem to be removing the tables. Does drupal have a mechanism to remove the tables?

Comment: If the drush command returns no results, you can delete the tables.

Comment: Ran into this problem after deleting fields via Drupal UI associated with config_pages module and then uninstalling the module without first running cron. Had to ```drush pm-install config_pages && drush php-eval 'field_purge_batch(1000);' && drush ev "var_dump(\Drupal::state()->get('field.storage.deleted'))"  &&  drush core-cron && drush pm-uninstall config_pages && drush core-cron && echo "DELETE FROM key_value WHERE key_value.name = 'config_pages'" | drush sql-cli && echo "DELETE FROM cachetags WHERE tag LIKE '%config_pages%'" | drush sql-cli```

Comment: I am running into the same issue with time_field module. Installed to test and now I am stuck with "  time_field: Fields pending deletion  " and cron does not seem to be doing the trick"