# Order of drush commands for automated deployment?

Tags: 8, drush, deployment

What order should the following drush commands be ran?

- config-import
- updatedb
- entity-updates

Also, I see entity-updates fail a lot due to field_delete_data* tables existing. How can I delete them as part of my automated deployment?

Comment: You shouldn't delete those tables yourself unless you're absolutely sure they are not being referenced. Cron should clean them up. See my question I asked about this recently https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/253055/can-i-delete-leftover-field-deleted-tables

Comment: The issue is that I cannot wait for cron to do the tidy up, as we do deployments as and when

Comment: You should not delete those tables at will - review that question as to the whys.

Comment: I've not yet encountered an issue in doing so :/

Answer (score 38):

Drush [10.3.0](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/tag/10.3.0) now provides a [`deploy`](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/4359) command to standardize how Drupal deployment works. This command performs the following:

> ```
> drush updatedb --no-cache-clear
> drush cache:rebuild
> drush config:import
> drush cache:rebuild
> drush deploy:hook
> ```

Database updates always come before configuration import! Support for automatic entity updates has been removed from Drupal core ([change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/3034742)) and `entup` has been removed from Drush core. Whenever an entity type or field storage definition needs to be created, changed or deleted, it has to be done via `hook_update_N()`.

---

Here is the updated deployment routine I'm happiest with.

```
drush state:set system.maintenance_mode 1
drush cache:rebuild
git pull
composer install --no-dev
drush deploy
drush state:set system.maintenance_mode 0
drush cache:rebuild
```

---

This also means you have to run two releases if you want to uninstall and remove a contrib module. First release to deploy the updated config that disables the module. Second release to deploy the updated composer.json and lock file after you removed it with Composer.

To make real consecutive releases possible you might want to pass the current release's commit SHA1 to the deployment script and then replace `git pull` with a more exact routine (where `$1` is the SHA1):

```
# If not empty 1st argument passed to the script, do:
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
  git reset --hard "$1"
else
  git pull
fi
```

Otherwise the consecutiveness can not be guaranteed when you push two new releases at once or within a short period. As then the first release's triggered `git pull` will simply pull the latest changes (from the second release), where instead it should pull only the changes included in the first release. See the full sample repo [`leymannx/drupal-circleci-behat`](https://github.com/leymannx/drupal-circleci-behat).

Credit for this `git` snippet goes to [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/). This is how they are doing it in their containers.

Comment: I'm strongly against using entup in such a workflow. Modules must provide update functions for their entity type changes, entup is not reliable (there are many changes that it can't do and will fail with an exception) and should only be used when developing a not-yet-released entity type. It's something that non-cli users *can not* execute.

Comment: Since the answer mentions composer: It is recommended to run `composer install` with [autoloader optimization options](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/autoloader-optimization.md) such as `--optimize-autoloader`.

Comment: So am I reading this right that you run cache:rebuild 5 times? 2 inside the new drush deploy and 3 outside of that?

Comment: I've added a `git clean -fd config/sync` after the `git pull` in my deployment scripts. On our small projects, config changes on live are allowed and common, and if live changed a config that needed to be removed by dev later, then that changed config file on live was not deleted by git. The `git clean -fd config/sync` then removes all left-over config files (where config/sync is the path of your configuarion sync directory).

Comment: @ElijahLynn You would have to. If you update the maintenance mode setting, you have to rebuild the cache for it to take effect.

Answer (score 4):

The sequence of commands should be:

```sh
updatedb (which runs update hooks)
config-import
```

You do not want to run entity-updates because it is deprecated, see https://www.drupal.org/node/3034742. Instead, rely on update hooks (hook_update_N) to properly modify any database schema or necessary configurations.

It is imperative that updatedb is the first command run that boots Drupal after code has been changed. You can see https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/3100553 for some commentary on what issues might arise when that is not done.

## Example Deployment Script

Here is an example deployment script that has had a lot of review and discussion behind it, but consider it a starting point. It's likely there will be adjustments you would want to make. It does assume you're deploying an artifact (notice that composer install is not run on deployment).

```sh
drush sset system.maintenance_mode TRUE
# Create a restore point by taking backups of anything that is not in the code repository: database, media, cache
# Checkout the code you are deploying
drush updb
drush cim sync -y || drush cim sync -y
drush cim sync -y
drush sset system.maintenance_mode FALSE
drush cr
```

You can see https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2020/03/11/automate-drupal-deployments/ for a deeper explanation behind this. See also https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/4359/ which is a PR to include a deploy command in Drush.

I mentioned the script above is a starting point, I've documented some variations that you might want to apply to that script (or any deploy script you use) that might be helpful: https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2020/03/12/automated-drupal-deployment-and-rollback-recipes/

Answer (score 3):

Here is our CI script, quite the same :)

```
drush cr
git pull
composer install
# drupal console enforce modules are enabled before any config is installed
drupal config:import:single --directory="config/sync" --file="core.extension.yml"
drush cr
drush -y updb
drush cr
drush -y cim
drush cr
```

the config:import:single was helpfull when diffrent developers where creating modules without requiring the correct dependencies in their .info.yml

Comment: Ah I think this was the reason why we did run drush cim befor drush updb once. So this looks like a much better solution just in case somone forgets to put the correct dependencies into the info.yml

Answer (score 2):

If you need to import custom translations too make sure to run a drush cim afterwards importing as some of the lables are translated in config and some in the po files.

At moment our update job looks like this after a git pull.
And make sure if you are on dev to export your changes before pulling with drush cex ;-) :

```
composer install --no-interaction -d /var/www/html/
drush updatedb -y
drush cr -y
drush cim -y


drush locale:check -y #make sure to switch this to local only in settings.php in production
drush locale:update -y
drush locale:import de ../translations/custom-translations.de.po --type=customized --override=all -y
drush locale:import de ../translations/custom_other_translations.de.po --type=customized --override=all -y
drush cr -y

drush cim -y
drush cr -y
```

Comment: Database updates always need to run before configuration import.

Comment: You could be right on that, normally. But I am pretty sure we had some reason we did put it there later on while running in trouble with some config splits. Will re-check this.

Comment: corrected the order in between

Answer (score 1):

Use `drush deploy`, it calls eveything in needed order + as bonus you can use https://www.drush.org/latest/commands/deploy_hook/ which will allow you to manage content changes with new updated/imported structure.