# Does "composer remove drupal/module" actually uninstall the module first?

Tags: composer

Does `composer remove drupal/module` actually uninstall the module first,  especially in  multi-site environments?

On the other hand, does `composer require` "enable" the given module for all sites?

Comment: See [Order of Drush commands for automated deployment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/254411/15055), it has a paragraph about consecutive releases. `This also means to run two releases if you want to remove a contrib module completely. First release to disable the module. Second release to have it removed by Composer.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, Composer doesn’t install or uninstall modules in the site itself.

It’s a dependency manager; all it does is compute your requirements, then download them.

You might be able to add a post install/update command to automate it, but trying to make it generic would probably be a pain.

Comment: So it is possible to crush the site letting composer remove installed module ?

Comment: Yes, it would be like deleting a module folder without uninstalling it.

Comment: Is your recommendation to first uninstall the module via Drupal Admin Panel and then run composer remove drupal/module ?  Is that the proper way to do this?

Comment: Yes @Robbiegod, if you remove the files before uninstalling the module there’s a good chance you’ll brick the site until you replace them. BTW is too much to hope your username is a reference to the great Robbie “God” Fowler??

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I am not Mr Fowler.  I got the nickname awhile back when I worked at a game company (Take2) and it just kind of stuck.

Comment: @Robbiegod It's probably easier to uninstall the modules using Drush if you're already using command line for Composer. `drush pmu my_module` (short for `pm-uninstall`)

Answer (score 4):

In a Drupal site with a Composer workflow you'll need to do the following when you decide to remove a module:

1. From your Drupal Admin, uninstall/disable the module so that Drupal doesn't expect to see it.
2. Edit your composer.json file in the root of your Drupal installation. It should be outside the /web directory. Remove the reference to module module and save the file.
3. run composer update

Composer will remove the module from the file system and will know that it is no longer a package in the installation.

Comment: 1. Disable (prior to Drupal 8 you need to disable a module first) **and** uninstall the module. 2. Run `composer remove drupal/mymodule`. 3. Done

Comment: Do you know if remove drupal/mymodule works with Composer in Drupal 8? I have not attempted that.

Comment: @AndrewWasson It works.

Comment: Thanks @mbomb007