# Drupal config or routes stays inactive until I disable/re-enable related modules

Tags: 8, configuration

I know this might be a broad question but maybe someone had the same issue before.

Here is the issue:

1. I have installed some contributed module, (e.g Rules);
2. I have configured some rules;
3. Exported config via `drush cex`;
4. Pushed code and tried to import it on another machine or staging
   server;
5. Import via `drush cim` went successfully, no errors;
6. I see Rules module enabled from admin UI.
7. But: no admin menu items related to Rules module show up.
8. When I try to access Rules related routes I get 404s.
9. I disable Rules module and re-enable it and now menu items show up and routes start to work.
10. I run `druch cim` again to re-import my specific Rules and everything is fine.

So this happens not only for Rules but for every other module, does not matter if it is my custom modules or contributed modules, I have to disable/re-enable/re-config-import in order to make it work on other machines or even on my machine if I just pulled down new changes which I did not have before.

Comment: Have you tried to `drush cr` after `drush cim`?

Comment: @NoSssweat I am doing `drush cr` for every step to make sure I don't end up with caching problem but it looks like it is not a caching problem or proper caches are not cleared? I am not sure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order of drush commands for automated deployment?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/254407/order-of-drush-commands-for-automated-deployment)