# How do I update configuration/database after a core update?

Tags: 8, updating

This may seem like a dumb question to some of you, I'm sure. After having worked with Drupal from version 6, I'm now for the first time using Drupal 8 and -- after some initial difficulties -- have actually come to enjoy the new development process (using Composer and Configuration Management etc.). However, I'm still failing to understand the indended workflow, after having completed a core update in my local installation. Here's my understanding, so far:

1. In case of simpler modifications -- like, say, having created a new content type -- I usually call `drush cex` on my local Drupal site, then transfer the contents of the sync directory to my staging (or production, if I'm feeling venturous) site (using FTP) and go to `Configuration > Development > Configuration Synchronization` to apply the changes. (Note that I can't call `drush cim` at this point, as I'm not able to use the terminal in my staging/production site.)
2. If any content has been created for that new content type in my local site, I transfer that content to staging using the `Deploy` module.

So far, that's working pretty well. However, how am I supposed to proceed, after having completed a bigger update that involves non-trivial modifications to the database?

1. Say, I'm performing a core update: `composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies`
2. I will then perform the necessary database updates locally, either by calling `drush updatedb` or by visiting `update.php` in a browser.

But then what?

Say, I'll upload all the new files via FTP to the staging site. Clearly, I cannot also copy the local database to the staging site, because the contents would be overwritten. So, I need to import the new configuration to the staging site... but accessing `Configuration > Development > Configuration Synchronization` to update the database will probably result in an error, exactly because the database has not been updated, yet.

This is where I'm stuck. I suspect, there's a piece to the puzzle that I'm missing, but what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating Drupal 8 roughly goes like this. First in a **local** instance of your site:

- Run `composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies` to update core. (Updating all dependencies including contrib would be `composer update --with-dependencies`.)
- Now apply database updates by either `drush -y updb` or by visiting /update.php in your browser.
- Next export the config that may have changed now by either `drush -y cex` or from your Drupal back-end in the browser.
- Git commit and push the updated composer.lock file and the updated config files.

Next on your **live** site you roughly do the same, but now import the config at the end.

- Git pull the updated composer.lock and config.
- Run `composer install --no-dev` to update the files.
- Run `drush -y updb` or visit /update.php to apply the database updates.
- Run `drush -y cim` or visit your admin settings to import the updated config that now should match the one you exported locally earlier.

For a more advanced deployment flow, for example flushing cache and activating the maintenance mode, see my other answer on [Order of drush commands for automated deployment?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/254407/order-of-drush-commands-for-automated-deployment)

Comment: Thank you very much, very helpful. In all previous explanations of this process I was somehow missing the connection between updating the database and importing the configuration. The only thing I would add would be the process without using the composer on the live site, as, again, I can only use the terminal locally. So far, I have simply uploaded the updated site via FTP... is that what's intended?

Comment: @MarcusC. – FTP is not ideal, as it is a lengthy and insecure process, SFTP would be a bit better, but yeah, that's how it works when you don't have access to the command line and Composer.