# What is the best practice to update our internal code from Dev to Prod for multiple sites?

Tags: deployment

**Details:**
We are not sure of the best practice to use for updating internal code, such as custom modules and theme. There seems to be two main processes to take and both look like the correct answer. Can you please help guide me into the correct workflow?

1. hook_update_N() - We have been writing hook updates in our custom modules and then running drush updb.
2. Config import/export - We also export the config changes so that we can build new sites with the same config files. However, we don't use config import on our live sites. This is where I am not sure what we should be doing.

**Setup:** We have a multi-site setup where all sites are using the same core code, this includes custom modules, main theme, and a admin theme (along with contrib modules, core, and libraries).

**Question:** If we were to update a couple of the config files inside our custom module (let's say a form display). Then we wanted to push this to our live site. Would we:

A) Write a hook_update_N() function to update the DB, save to git, run composer update (grabbing the new .install file) and then run drush updb.

B) Export the config changes (drush cex), save to git, run composer update (grabbing new config files) and then run drush cim to import the new config files to update the DB?

Comment: Why don't you using config_import on live sites?

Comment: You should use both update hooks and config regardless of the environment. Each have their own purpose in your application. If you need site variations, then you could look into using runtime overrides or https://www.drupal.org/project/config_split just as an example.

Comment: How do you know when to use the update hooks and when to use the config_import?

Comment: You can only import config if you have a cloned site (having the same config UUIDs). Then config import is the preferred way.

Comment: Is this maybe a duplicate of [Order of drush commands for automated deployment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/254407/15055)?

Comment: Leymannax - I am asking a slightly different question. If I am updating field that is in one of my custom modules on my dev environment and want to update my live site. I would first update the config file in /config/install. Then what would I do next? Would I create a hook_update_N() function to write to the DB and run drush updb, or would I simply run config_import to update the field? I am trying to determine when to use each of these items.

Comment: 4k4 - I am removing all UUID's and _Core hash from my config files so I don't hit any issues. I am just trying to figure out when I should use hook_update_n() and when I should just run config_import. Is there a benefit of running one over the other?

Comment: The default config of a module is usually not part of a deployment process from dev to prod. When you install a module via deploying the config the default config is ignored and instead the exported config is used.