# Import configuration in CI/CD script does not work

Tags: 8, drush, importing-exporting

I have a Drupal 8.9.13.
I wanted to install a new module, for example the google_tag. But in my case I do that in my CI/CD process. So to do that I did the following actions:

1. edit the composer.json in a way to contain the new module
2. the composer.lock is updated for the same reason (by enabling the module using drush)
3. updated the core.extension.yml in a way to contain a line
4. generated the *.settings.yml by exporting the configuration.

During the deployment, first of all the code source is get from the git repo and then a 'composer install' is called.
After that a "./vendor/bin/drush config-import -y" is called to import the configuration of the new module (event the module wasn't configured, there is a default config).
And here I have the following error:

Unable to install the google_tag module since it does not exist.

Does someone have any idea what might be the problem?

I saw also that in Drupal's database in the table config for the value of core.extension I have a value which usually describes the activated modules and the one I am trying to activate is not there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order of drush commands for automated deployment?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/254407/order-of-drush-commands-for-automated-deployment)

Comment: @leymannx Wow great find! I'm switching to this command in our own scripts now!

Comment: @leymannx thank's for the link. Yes, it gives some insights to the process of deployment and how the thing should be organised. I am not an expert in Drupal and I can't say how much the problem discussed in the link you gave is close to my case. But it was interesting to read it :)

Comment: Does the problem persist when you use `drush -y deploy` or `drush cr && drush -y cim` instead? That's why I linked this question.

Comment: Doing the drush commands in the order you said, solves the issue :)

Comment: 2: the composer.lock is NOT updated by drush

Comment: @Rafael1 , explain pls, otherwise your comment is NOT useful.

Answer (score 0):

After running `composer install`, you need to add a `drush cr` before you run `drush cim`. All together:

```
composer install
./vendor/bin/drush cr
./vendor/bin/drush config-import -y
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tested it and it worked. However it remains to me to understand what exactly is the purpose of "drush cr" and how it reflects to the following "drush config-import -y". 
I am still a newbie with Drupal and the concept of "cache rebuild" command is not very clear not me. I'm asking myself how the cache is related to the configuration ..?

Comment: Composer adds the requirements into vendor. modules and theme folders for drupal. Drush cr is shorthand for cache-rebuild, there are a few different types of caches, and one of them relates to what modules and themes exist. Config import often times will enable or uninstall a module/theme, so it needs a fresh cache to know what is there and what is not.