# How to update a module in production?

Tags: 8, configuration, composer

I am using git to deploy my composer.lock to production. Contrib is not part of my git repo. Therefore, in production I then run `composer install` to add contrib to production.

What happens when I update a module in dev via `composer update`, then deploy the updated composer.lock to production and run `composer install` there? Will it update/replace the existing module code or what is the best practices to update a module in production without having to run the resource hungry `composer update` command in production?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order of drush commands for automated deployment?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/254407/order-of-drush-commands-for-automated-deployment)

Comment: Update locally using composer update drupal/module_name, then run database updates, then export config. Commit updated lock file and config. Deploy. On Live, set the page in maintenance mode, run composer install or deploy latest vendor from CI, run database updates, import config, disable maintenance mode. Done.

Comment: @leymanxx: Very clear. Thanks for summarizing the process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What happens when I update a module in dev via composer update, then
> deploy the updated composer.lock to production and run composer
> install there? Will it update/replace the existing module code

Yes. Running `composer install` is a fairly lightweight command that will install the components of the system exactly as they have been recorded in `composer.lock` which is essentially a snapshot of the codebase. As you will have committed `composer.lock` containing references to the updated code, when you run `composer install` on any server, it will update the code to match `composer.lock` which has the updated code.

Running `composer update` updates code versions, and is much more resource intensive.

I wrote a blog series on Composer and Drupal a couple of years back which explains this all in more depth: https://www.morpht.com/blog/drupal-and-composer-part-1-understanding-composer

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was unsure about. Thanks for clarifying!!!

Comment: Note that many people consider it a security risk to have Composer installed on a production server, as access to the server could allow someone to install software using it.

Comment: Thanks for the watchout!! I would guess that if someone gains access to composer, the problem is not with composer, but with the server config in general. The attacker would have loads of possibilities to do harm even if composer was not installed.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't actually decided which side of the fence I fall on for this one. I'm not a server guy though.